# Debugging a simple ARM 64-bit executable causes internal error in GDB

Tags: gcc, arm, gdb

I wrote a simple C program to print hello world. Then I ran it through

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -ohello hello.c -static -g3
gdb-multiarch hello
```

After this, I `run` and gdb encounters an internal error:

```
Reading symbols from hello...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/gt/hello
/build/gdb-GT4MLW/gdb-8.1/gdb/i387-tdep.c:592: internal-error: void i387_supply_fxsave(regcache*, int, const void*): Assertion `tdep->st0_regnum >= I386_ST0_REGNUM' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
Quit this debugging session? (y or n)
```

Here's the output of `file hello`:

```
hello: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=a...b, with debug_info, not stripped
```

This is my `hello.c`:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
        printf("hello world");
        return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What else do I need to do? I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on an x86_64 machine.

When I use `gdb hello`, I am unable to use breakpoints, I get this error:

```
Reading symbols from hello...done.
(gdb) break 4
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400404: file hello.c, line 4.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/gt/hello
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 1.
Cannot access memory at address 0x400404
(gdb)
```

I am following the guide given on [this page](https://gist.github.com/Liryna/10710751) under the first section.

Answer (score 3):

In order to run and debug your AArch64 executable, you (in general) need to run it on an AArch64 machine, or in an AArch64 emulator.

You might have some setup where qemu more or less transparently emulates aarch64 binaries for you - but that doesn't work quite as transparently for the debugger. In general you can run the debugger on one machine, connected over a network to a debugging server on a different machine, allowing you to debug a process running on the machine with the debugging server.

The guide you linked shows how to set up qemu to allow it to transparently emulate binaries as you execute them. That guide only shows executing, not debugging, but it has got a link "Debugging using GDB" that points to https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2010979&s=096fb05dbd59acbfc8542b71f4b590db&p=12061325#post12061325, where it is explained how to debug a process which executes within qemu emulation. This essentially amounts to the same remote debugging with a debugging server as I mentioned above.

The essential bits of this post is this:

```
# In a terminal
$ qemu-arm-static -g 10101 ./hello

# In a new terminal
$ gdb-multiarch 
(gdb) target remote :10101
Remote debugging using :10101
[New Remote target]
[Switching to Remote target]
```